# Erlang json validation issue

Tags: mysql, json, database, validation, erlang

I'm kinda new to erlang

trying to make JSON validation using https://github.com/Prots/olifer

but getting error:

1> sql_app:update(<<"0.2851">>,<<"frfrfrfr">>).

** exception error: no case clause matching [{<<"0.2851">>,
                                              <<"FORMAT_ERROR">>}]
     in function  sql_app:update/2 (c:/sql/_build/default/lib/sql/src/sql_app.erl, line 31)

the function is:

```
update(Id, Info) ->
  case olifer:validate(Id, [{<<"string">>, <<"required">>}]) of
    {ok, _} ->  
    emysql:prepare(info, <<"UPDATE vobla SET info = ? WHERE id = ?">>),
      Result1 = emysql:execute(erlang, info, [Info, Id]),
      io:format("~n~p~n", [Result1]);
    {errors, _} -> io:format("~n~p~n", [error])
  end.
```

Could you please help me to figure it out.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the case clause you have written does not match the result passed `[{<<"0.2851">>, <<"FORMAT_ERROR">>}]`. Your case clauses matches tuples of the format `{ok, _}` or `{errors, _}`. Not a list.

```
update(Id, Info) ->
  Res = olifer:validate(Id, [{<<"string">>, <<"required">>}]),
  io:format("~p", [Res]),
  case Res of
    [Tup] -> do_something; % could be an error
    {ok, _} ->  % validation success
    emysql:prepare(info, <<"UPDATE vobla SET info = ? WHERE id = ?">>),
      Result1 = emysql:execute(erlang, info, [Info, Id]),
      io:format("~n~p~n", [Result1]);
    {errors, _err} -> io:format("~n~p~n", [_err])
  end.
```

You are having a format error as per the log.

Comment: you're right. I've added _ -> io:format("~n~p~n", [error]) and now I am getting just "error" in shell. but I think the main problem is bad format of the json validation case olifer:validate(Id, [{<<"string">>, <<"required">>}]) of

Comment: You must be printing `errors`. And yes, the validate is giving you a list, not a tuple. Try printing what the result of validate is and update the case pattern.